# Use external class in typescript and avoid using reference

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using rusha for sha1 hashing and gulp-typescript for compiling typescript.

There is no dt for rusha so I created a definition and stored it under `typings/custom/rusha.d.ts`:

```
declare class Rusha {
    digest(data: any): string;
    digestFromString(strityng: string): string;
}
```

and installed it via `typings install file:typings/custom/rusha.d.ts --global`.

this is the relevant part of my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpTS = require('gulp-typescript');
var gulpSourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var tsConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('script', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/script/**/*.ts')
      .pipe(gulpSourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(gulpTS(tsConfig.compilerOptions))
      .pipe(gulpSourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/script'));
});
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Now I created a class `User` in a file `src/script/User.ts` with the following contents:

```
export class User {
    public username: string;
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public email: string;

    private sha1Password: string;
    private rusha: Rusha = new Rusha();

    set password(value: string) {
        this.sha1Password = this.rusha.digest(value);
    }

    public checkPassword(password: string) {
        return this.sha1Password === this.rusha.digest(password);
    }

    public setSha1Password(sha1Password: string) {
        this.sha1Password = sha1Password;
    }
}
```

The problem:

```
$ npm run gulp script

> xxx@xxx gulp /home/xxx/path/to/xxx
> gulp "script"

[08:29:25] Using gulpfile ~/path/to/xxx/gulpfile.js
[08:29:25] Starting 'script'...
src/script/User.ts(9,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Rusha'.
src/script/User.ts(9,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Rusha'.
[08:29:27] TypeScript: 2 semantic errors
[08:29:27] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[08:29:27] Finished 'script' after 1.66 s
```

When I add `///<reference path="../../typings/custom/rusha.d.ts"/>` it works as well as `///<reference path="../../typings/globals/rusha/index.d.ts"/>`. But when I add `///<reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts"/>` it throws a lot of duplicate declarations and so on.

It seems this file get not loaded but others get loaded (for example Set from core-js). But not only `index.d.ts` looks correct. Also `typings.json` looks correct:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046",
    "rusha": "file:typings/custom/rusha.d.ts"
  }
}
```

Comment: I found out that the problem is gulp-typescript. It is simply not using the correct typings.
https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues/421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gulp-tsc has similar problems. The only solution I found so far is to add the custom ts definitions to the gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpTS = require('gulp-typescript');
var gulpSourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var tsConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('script', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    './typings/index.d.ts',
    './src/script/**/*.ts'
  ])
      .pipe(gulpSourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(gulpTS(tsConfig.compilerOptions))
      .pipe(gulpSourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/script'));
});
```